# Powershell: copy-item attach .vhdx to VM

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

My goal is to create a new VM, copy a `.vhdx` to a location, add the `.vhdx` to the new VM and then boot form it.

My issue is that the `.vhdx` is not attaching to the VM. I'm not sure why.

I want to say the `Copy-Item` is wrong since it get hung when I run that line, at least it seems that way as it never completes and I am trying this on an `SSD` drive.

```
$VM_NAME = "PS_TEST_VM"
$VM_RAM = 1GB
$VM_RAM_MAX = 2GB
$VM_CPUS = "4"
$VM_DEST_PATH = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks"
$VM_TO_COPY = "WIN81.1.vhdx"
$VM_HOST = "MAINKITTEN"
$NETWORK_SWITCH = "DEFAULTSWITCH"
$ROOT_VHD_TPL = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\WIN81.1.vhdx"

# CREATE
New-VM -Name $VM_NAME -Path $VM_DEST_PATH -NoVHD -Generation 2 -MemoryStartupBytes $VM_RAM -SwitchName $NETWORK_SWITCH 
Set-VM -Name $VM_NAME -ProcessorCount $VM_CPUS -DynamicMemory -MemoryMinimumBytes $VM_RAM -MemoryStartupBytes $VM_RAM -MemoryMaximumBytes $VM_RAM_MAX
# COPY AND ATTACH
Copy-Item -Path "${VM_DEST_PATH}\${VM_TO_COPY}" -Destination "${VM_DEST_PATH}\${VM_NAME}.vhdx"
Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName $VM_NAME -path "${VM_DEST_PATH}\${VM_NAME}.vhdx"

Start-VM $VM_NAME
echo "done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried copying the `.vhdx` first using the `-Force` parameter, then creating the new VM with the [existing VHD parameter set syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh848537(v=wps.620).aspx)?

**Syntax**

```
Parameter Set: Existing VHD
New-VM [[-Name] <String> ] [[-MemoryStartupBytes] <Int64> ] -VHDPath <String> [-AsJob] 
             [-BootDevice <BootDevice> ] [-ComputerName <String[]> ] [-Path <String> ] 
                    [-SwitchName <String> ] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

**Code**

```
# COPY
Copy-Item -Path "${VM_DEST_PATH}\${VM_TO_COPY}" -Destination "${VM_DEST_PATH}\${VM_NAME}.vhdx" -Force
# CREATE and Attach vhdx
New-VM -Name $VM_NAME -MemoryStartupBytes $VM_RAM -VHDPath "${VM_DEST_PATH}\${VM_NAME}.vhdx" -Path $VM_DEST_PATH -SwitchName $NETWORK_SWITCH -Generation 2
Set-VM -Name $VM_NAME -ProcessorCount $VM_CPUS -DynamicMemory -MemoryMinimumBytes $VM_RAM -MemoryStartupBytes $VM_RAM -MemoryMaximumBytes $VM_RAM_MAX

Start-VM $VM_NAME
```